# Powershell Start-Job won't run

Tags: powershell, background, start-job

I'm trying to run a simple job process in powershell 2.0 and it doesn't seem to run.

```
    $job = Start-Job { Return "Some string." }
```

When I call $job, the status says it's running. But the problem is that it never completes.

Tried the same thing on my Windows 7 machine and it completes immediately.

I'm running powershell 2.0 on windows xp.

Does anyone know what is causing this problem? How can I fix this problem?

This is my `$PSVersionTable`

```
    Name                           Value
    ----                           -----
    PSVersion                      2.0
    PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
    BuildVersion                   6.0.6002.18111
    PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
    WSManStackVersion              2.0
    CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.1
    SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: A simpler repro would be `Start-Job { 1 }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say your XP configuration of PowerShell is "somewhat" modified.  :-)  It should be running on CLR version 2.0 e.g.:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.3615
BuildVersion                   6.0.6002.18111
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

Try resetting the reg hack (or the Powershell.exe.config mod) so that PowerShell 2.0 is running on .NET 2.0 and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: Keith, Thank you! You are absolutely correct. Apparently when you load powershell under .net 4 using the powershell.exe.config method, background job does not work. However, it looks like this is only true under Windows XP since my Windows 7 install--which loads under .net 4 also--runs background job just fine.